# Does the identity function always exist in elementary set theory?

Tags: set-theory

Given only the axioms of extensionality, empty set, pairing, union and separation can the following sentence be proven?:

$$
\forall y\ \{(x,x) \mid x\in y\} \text{ is a set}
$$

Using a classic set definition of the ordered pair (such as Kuratowski's, Wiener's or Hausdorff's) it seems to hold for finite sets $y$, since the universe of hereditarily finite sets can act as a model, but is this formula valid?

Comment: @user953376: The OP does _not_ have the power set axiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a set "modest" if it has rank $<\omega+\omega$ and contains only finitely many elements of rank $\ge\omega+1$. (It can contain infinitely many elements with rank $\le\omega$, though).

The set of hereditarily modest sets is a model of all your axioms. It contains $\mathcal P(\omega)$ but not $\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathcal P(\omega)\}$.

Comment: Quine-Rosser pairs are a bit trickier, but with those it turns out the selected axioms cannot even prove that $(x,x)$ always exists. To see this consider the sets that hereditarily satisfy "$x\setminus\mathbb N$ is finite". Then we definitely have $\mathbb N$, but $(\mathbb N,\mathbb N)$ contains infinitely many "shifted" naturals that are not themselves naturals.